# Marshal.PtrToStructure crashing on 64bit

Tags: c#, crash, 64-bit, pinvoke

My unit tests crash on this bit of code when running in 64bit.

The crash happens on the **Marshal.PtrToStructure** call on the 2nd iteration of the loop. The "entriesRead" says 4 so it should be able to read correctly, but it does not. The Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WinAPI.NETAPI32.USER_INFO_4)) is 192 bytes in 64bit. Is this the source of the error?

```
    ....
    try {
            int entriesRead;
            int totalEntries;
            int resumeHandle;
            var result = WinAPI.NETAPI32.NetUserEnum(
                this.NTCompatibleHostName,
                3,
                2,
                out bufPtr,
                -1,
                out entriesRead,
                out totalEntries,
                out resumeHandle
            );
            if (result != 0) {
                throw new NetApiException(
                    result,
                    "Failed to enumerate local users on host '{0}'",
                    Host
                );
            }
            var structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WinAPI.NETAPI32.USER_INFO_4));
            var startAddr = bufPtr.ToInt64();
            var endAddr = startAddr + entriesRead * structSize;
            for (var offset = startAddr; offset < endAddr; offset += structSize) {
                var userInfo =
                    (WinAPI.NETAPI32.USER_INFO_4)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                        new IntPtr(offset),
                        typeof(WinAPI.NETAPI32.USER_INFO_4)

                    );

            }
        } catch (Exception error) {
        } 

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct USER_INFO_4 {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_name;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_password;
            public uint usri4_password_age;
            public uint usri4_priv;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_home_dir;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_comment;
            public uint usri4_flags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_script_path;
            public uint usri4_auth_flags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_full_name;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_usr_comment;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_parms;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_workstations;
            public uint usri4_last_logon;
            public uint usri4_last_logoff;
            public uint usri4_acct_expires;
            public uint usri4_max_storage;
            public uint usri4_units_per_week;
            public IntPtr usri4_logon_hours;
            public uint usri4_bad_pw_count;
            public uint usri4_num_logons;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_logon_server;
            public uint usri4_country_code;
            public uint usri4_code_page;
            public IntPtr usri4_user_sid;
            public uint usri4_primary_group_id;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_profile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string usri4_home_dir_drive;
            public uint usri4_password_expired;
        }


        [DllImport("netapi32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public static extern NET_API_STATUS NetUserEnum([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string servername, int level, int filter, out IntPtr bufptr, int prefmaxlen, out int entriesread, out int totalentries, out int resume_handle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struct is translated correctly. Its size is correct. Your translation of the function call is correct.

The problem is that you are passing level 3. Which means that the function returns `USER_INFO_3` rather than `USER_INFO_4`. The documentation of `NetUserEnum` makes absolutely no mention of it ever returning `USER_INFO_4` values. In order to get `USER_INFO_4` values you must call `NetUserGetInfo`.

Call `NetUserEnum` passing the server name and a level value of `0`. This will enumerate the user names. Then pass each of those user names, along with the server name, to `NetUserGetInfo` with a level of 4.

Comment: Amazingly, this apparently worked on x86 for many years. Maybe a source of random crashes. I ended up implementing USER_INFO_3 structure which was 184 bytes.